# Why can I only change my hat once every 10 seconds?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

I got the following error and got really curious:

> You may only change your hat once every 10 seconds.

Not that that's something that annoys me in any way, perfectly fine restriction, I just try again and it only happened because I miss clicked first.

But I can't help to wonder the reason (probably technical) behind this. Is it too resource heavy to change hat?

Because it's not something that would generate a polluted log to look add, like asking questions or editing comments and such. So I can only guess the reason.

Comment: *But I can't help but wonder...* I have to wonder too. Why would you need to change your hat more than once every 10 seconds, so you'd need to care about the limit? (And note that *change* does not mean *reposition on your head*, but *place a new hat on your head* - how many times IRL do you change hats every 10 seconds?)

Comment: I don't need to! As I mentioned, that's not something that annoys me in any way whatsoever, I was just curious for the reason behind it.

Comment: The reason behind it is because the developers at SE decided it should be the minimum. This is similar to the question I saw in the *Hot Network Questions* that asked *Why did <this fictional character> dislike <this other fictional character> on sight?* - the answer is clearly *because the author decided that was the case*.

Comment: @KenWhite That question (especially if it's [the one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/148634/481) I think it was) was almost definitely on a site where they'd be asking "in universe". So, to continue your analogy, they're asking what's the author's reasoning.

Comment: "Why?" questions should always make it clear what kind of answer you want. Is it "can anyone think of a good reason why this is a good idea?", or is it "who made the decision and when, and did they state their rationale?"

Comment: Guys how do you resize your hat? I made my hat to small and now I am unable to make it big.

Comment: Software without rate limiting is broken. Why _wouldn't_ you have a limit?

Comment: You have too much time on your hands if asking questions like this is a high priority

Comment: The phrase "barking hatstand" springs to mind :-)

Comment: I have no idea why this question has attracted so many downvotes. The OP clearly said " it only happened because I miss clicked first." so it's not like they were trying to set the world record in hat rotating or something.

Comment: can someone let me know , why this new "hat" feature? I mean motto behind this?

Comment: @vishwaratna "fun".

Comment: @MrLister I just asked my friend that is my hat visible to him and he said no, but I can clearly see a hat in my profile!! What's wrong?

Comment: @vishwaratna Your friend obviously doesn't know that your cup is a hat.

Answer (score 69):

#### How fast can you change hats in real life?

(be aware that you need to set the hat correctly on your head, and that you need to put the old one on its designated spot on the shelf).

---

*Everything* is rate limited. The hat changing limit is even mentioned in [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange. It would be hard to DDoS Stack Overflow just by changing your hat too often, but they *had* to set a limit.

Comment: I imagined there was a request limit per IP to avoid DDoS, but that seems a reasonable security measure too, to avoid other methods

Comment: Oh, beware that a hat change might be just a little tilt, not necessarily exchanging the hat. So I guess I can beat one per ten seconds :p

Comment: [These guys](https://youtu.be/Qdfe4Csl3FM?t=1m16s) took 96 hours to put on their hats. 10 seconds seems luxurious.

Comment: Although being DDoS by hats has yet to be proven, there is a record of [earlier promotional events](http://stackstatus.net/post/115305251014/outage-postmortem-march-31-2015) that *did* cause outage due to load ...

Comment: [Within around 2 seconds.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Caqup7dkaDE)

Comment: What is this "shelf" thing you refer to?  I thought the designated spot was on the floor.

Comment: Hats are synced between SE servers. Aside from  DDoS, a simple race condition problem might be the reason. Imagine that every server is own thread with own TLS and every time you change hat attribute on one, others should see that. If you changed it again, some other thread received  the update on one system, then changed own hat status before second update came, it generated another update with other sites. Status of hat on third site would be undetermined.  Or they start constantly to flip the hat around. Setting time frame in which that update is ignored may solve the issue